# AttributeError: Can't get attribute '_VariableFunctionClass' on <module 'torch._C' from 'xxx/torch/_C.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'>'

Tags: python, pickle, ubuntu-18.04

I trained a model and stored it with pickle. But when I try to load it on another ubuntu, it shows the error.

```sh
AttributeError: Can't get attribute '_VariableFunctionClass' on <module 'torch._C' from 'xxx/torch/_C.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'>'
```

I have tried the method below but it does not work:

```py
    class CustomUnpickler(pickle.Unpickler):

    def find_class(self, module, name):
        try:
            return super().find_class(__name__, name)
        except AttributeError:
            return super().find_class(module, name)

pickle_data = CustomUnpickler(open(path, 'rb')).load()
```

I also tried with the pickle that are trained with cpu, and it does not trigger that error. So I'm wondering if it's the GPU dependencies that cause this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the versions of PyTorch on each system?  Pickles are not guaranteed to be compatible between different versions of the source code that produced/loaded them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try to make the enviroment the same.
On the generating one is pytorch 1.8.1 py3.7_cuda11.1_cudnn8.0.5_0
and on the loading one is pytorch 1.3.1  cuda100py37h53c1284_0

Comment: That is most likely the problem then =)